# Yocto do_kernel_metadata failed with custom BSP

Tags: yocto, beagleboneblack, bitbake, bsp

I try to make a custom BSP for my board (a custom beaglebone).
It's my first time with yocto. I read many documentation and tutorials. But I can't solve my problem.

I've been using `yocto-bsp` when I've got a problem with the task `do_kernel_metadata`.

**Create a custom BSP**

```
$> yocto-bsp create biatime arm
> 4.12
> standard/beaglebone
> tune for cortex8
> smp yes
> xorg no
> keyboard yes
> screen no
```

**Configure bblayer to get __meta-biatime__**

```
# POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION is increased each time 

build/conf/bblayers.conf
# changes incompatibly
POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION = "2"

BBPATH = "${TOPDIR}"
BBFILES ?= ""

BBLAYERS ?= " \
  /home/initer/Documents/yocto/poky/meta \
  /home/initer/Documents/yocto/poky/meta-poky \
  /home/initer/Documents/yocto/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
  /home/initer/Documents/yocto/poky/meta-biatime \
  "
```

**Configure local.conf**

```
#MACHINE ?= "beaglebone"
#MACHINE ?= "genericx86"
#MACHINE ?= "genericx86-64"
#MACHINE ?= "mpc8315e-rdb"
#MACHINE ?= "edgerouter"
MACHINE ?= "biatime"
```

**bitbake core-image-minimal**

```
Loading cache: 100% |##################################################################| Time: 0:00:00
Loaded 1278 entries from dependency cache.
Parsing recipes: 100% |################################################################| Time: 0:00:02
Parsing of 820 .bb files complete (819 cached, 1 parsed). 1279 targets, 63 skipped, 0 masked, 0 errors.
NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies

Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION           = "1.36.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "universal"
TARGET_SYS           = "arm-poky-linux-gnueabi"
MACHINE              = "biatime"
DISTRO               = "poky"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "2.4.2"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "arm armv7a vfp neon callconvention-hard cortexa8"
TARGET_FPU           = "hard"
meta                 
meta-poky            
meta-yocto-bsp       
meta-biatime         = "rocko:fdeecc901196bbccd7c5b1ea4268a2cf56764a62"

Initialising tasks: 100% |#############################################################| Time: 0:00:04
NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks
NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
ERROR: linux-yocto-4.12.20+gitAUTOINC+f8f75cc4d9_967d275130-r0.1 do_kernel_metadata: Could not locate BSP definition for biatime/standard and no defconfig was provided
ERROR: linux-yocto-4.12.20+gitAUTOINC+f8f75cc4d9_967d275130-r0.1 do_kernel_metadata: Function failed: do_kernel_metadata (log file is located at /home/initer/Documents/yocto/poky/build_biatime/tmp/work/biatime-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-yocto/4.12.20+gitAUTOINC+f8f75cc4d9_967d275130-r0.1/temp/log.do_kernel_metadata.28499)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/initer/Documents/yocto/poky/build_biatime/tmp/work/biatime-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-yocto/4.12.20+gitAUTOINC+f8f75cc4d9_967d275130-r0.1/temp/log.do_kernel_metadata.28499
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing python function extend_recipe_sysroot
| NOTE: Direct dependencies are ['/home/initer/Documents/yocto/poky/meta/recipes-kernel/kern-tools/kern-tools-native_git.bb:do_populate_sysroot']
| NOTE: Installed into sysroot: []
| NOTE: Skipping as already exists in sysroot: ['kern-tools-native', 'quilt-native']
| DEBUG: Python function extend_recipe_sysroot finished
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_kernel_metadata
| ERROR: Could not locate BSP definition for biatime/standard and no defconfig was provided
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Function failed: do_kernel_metadata (log file is located at /home/initer/Documents/yocto/poky/build_biatime/tmp/work/biatime-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-yocto/4.12.20+gitAUTOINC+f8f75cc4d9_967d275130-r0.1/temp/log.do_kernel_metadata.28499)
ERROR: Task (/home/initer/Documents/yocto/poky/meta/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-yocto_4.12.bb:do_kernel_metadata) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 1139 tasks of which 1118 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /home/initer/Documents/yocto/poky/meta/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-yocto_4.12.bb:do_kernel_metadata
Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

Since the beginning of the script generator, noting has changed on the meta-biatime.

Can you explain me what is the problem with my mind ?

Thank you for your support.

Comment: By putting `MACHINE = biatime` you want to create a new machine type, so you will need to tell which kernel to use for it, see [mega manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#platdev-newmachine-kernel)

Comment: I've created a recipes-kernel with the `yocto-bsp create`. The current solution is to add a **defconfig** file to the kernel and a **wic** directory with biatime.wks. No problem to build since this modification.