# Yocto bitbake core-image-sato with preempt-rt failed

Tags: linux, x86-64, yocto, preempt-rt

I want to set up a linux kernel with preempt-RT with yocto.

According to meta/recipes-rt/README, I add the following code in build/conf/local.conf, and do bitbake core-image-sato, but bitbake fail.

```
MACHINE ?= "genericx86-64"

PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel = "linux-yocto-rt"
COMPATIBLE_MACHINE_genericx86-64 = "genericx86-64"
COMPATIBLE_MACHINE_quilt-native = "genericx86-64"
```

Yocto output the following error:

```
NOTE: Bitbake server didn't start within 5 seconds, waiting for 90
Loading cache: 100% |#######################################################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:13
Loaded 1330 entries from dependency cache.
NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies

Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION           = "1.46.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "universal"
TARGET_SYS           = "x86_64-poky-linux"
MACHINE              = "genericx86-64"
DISTRO               = "poky"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "3.1.20"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "m64 core2"
TARGET_FPU           = ""
meta                 
meta-poky            
meta-yocto-bsp       = "dunfell:90a6f6a110ab14890e2f6a1616e74ee259fc0f8f"

Initialising tasks: 100% |##################################################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:48
Sstate summary: Wanted 14 Found 0 Missed 14 Current 1203 (0% match, 98% complete)
NOTE: Executing Tasks
ERROR: linux-yocto-rt-5.4.213+gitAUTOINC+2f18e629f7_03cd66d981-r0 do_kernel_metadata: Could not locate BSP definition for genericx86-64/preempt-rt and no defconfig was provided
ERROR: linux-yocto-rt-5.4.213+gitAUTOINC+2f18e629f7_03cd66d981-r0 do_kernel_metadata: Execution of '/media/fff/disk1T/yocto/demo3/poky/build/tmp/work/genericx86_64-poky-linux/linux-yocto-rt/5.4.213+gitAUTOINC+2f18e629f7_03cd66d981-r0/temp/run.do_kernel_metadata.1138429' failed with exit code 1
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /media/fff/disk1T/yocto/demo3/poky/build/tmp/work/genericx86_64-poky-linux/linux-yocto-rt/5.4.213+gitAUTOINC+2f18e629f7_03cd66d981-r0/temp/log.do_kernel_metadata.1138429
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing python function extend_recipe_sysroot
| NOTE: Direct dependencies are ['/media/fff/disk1T/yocto/demo3/poky/meta/recipes-kernel/kern-tools/kern-tools-native_git.bb:do_populate_sysroot']
| NOTE: Installed into sysroot: []
| NOTE: Skipping as already exists in sysroot: ['kern-tools-native', 'quilt-native']
| DEBUG: Python function extend_recipe_sysroot finished
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_kernel_metadata
| NOTE: do_kernel_metadata: for summary/debug, set KCONF_AUDIT_LEVEL > 0
| ERROR: Could not locate BSP definition for genericx86-64/preempt-rt and no defconfig was provided
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Execution of '/media/fff/disk1T/yocto/demo3/poky/build/tmp/work/genericx86_64-poky-linux/linux-yocto-rt/5.4.213+gitAUTOINC+2f18e629f7_03cd66d981-r0/temp/run.do_kernel_metadata.1138429' failed with exit code 1
ERROR: Task (/media/fff/disk1T/yocto/demo3/poky/meta/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-yocto-rt_5.4.bb:do_kernel_metadata) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 3173 tasks of which 3172 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /media/fff/disk1T/yocto/demo3/poky/meta/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-yocto-rt_5.4.bb:do_kernel_metadata
Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

My hardware cpu is x86-64 core. It hint genericx86-64/preempt-rt dont exist, what action should I adapt to generate core-image-sato with preempt-RT? Please leave a comment and help me if you are similar with this problem.

I try to checkout various branch of yocto but doesn't matter.These dunfell、langdale、kirkstone.I expect to use dunfell.

Following is my build/conf/bblayers.conf:

```
POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION = "2"

BBPATH = "${TOPDIR}"
BBFILES ?= ""

BBLAYERS ?= " \
  /media/fff/disk1T/yocto/demo3/poky/meta \
  /media/fff/disk1T/yocto/demo3/poky/meta-poky \
  /media/fff/disk1T/yocto/demo3/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
 "
```

Comment: It would help if you provide your build/conf/bblayers.conf
For a time being this ressources could help https://www.rpsys.net/yocto-docs/bsp-guide/bsp.html#bsp-kernel-recipe-example

Comment: Oh, I will read this later, And I had post my /build/conf/bblayers.conf, please help me to check it, I learn to use yocto not long ago.Thinks a lot.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49770393/yocto-do-kernel-metadata-failed-with-custom-bsp

Comment: Thinks a lot, I realized there was lack of linux-yocto-rt.bbappend file in yocto project.